# Remove the duplicates expect one record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]
Here I wanted to delete all records with value 1 and only keep a single record

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: That looks like a public IP address as well, should you be sharing that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okay.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry it was my mistake

Comment: Note that that IP address has already likely been exposed and shared across many scraping sites at this stage, @ankitgiri . If you don't have good firewall rules, I suggest you ensure you do now. You might also want to raise a custom Flag to ask a moderator to remove the edit from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66874589/revisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your DBMS it's really tough to know which query you need. If your dbms supports cte and row_number() then below query will work.

```
with cte as
(select *,row_number()over(order by column_1)rn from table_name)t
delete cte where rn>1
```

In SQL Server this will work fine.

Comment: You are most welcome. It would be highly appreciated if you accept this answer since it worked. Best wishes.

Comment: @ankitgiri You wanted to remove all rows but one and this answer does that. Is there anything wrong? Just curious since you have unaccepted the answer. Though it’s only your choice to accept any answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given the nature of your data, I would suggest removing all rows and adding a new one back in:

```
truncate table t;

insert into t(column_1)
    values (1);
```

Be careful!  The `truncate table` removes all rows from the table.

Comment: It was asked in an interview he just wants to remove the duplicate data by keeping a single record. Using delete

Comment: @ankitgiri . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  `delete` is probably not the best way to do what you are asking.